# Converting string back to HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I took a HTML string from tinyMCE and wrapped it with jQuery html(). I am now trying to unwrap it and display it in the the view.

I get tinyMCE contents and put them into to a div. I then extract html contents of that div and pass it to my database via AJAX. I am now trying to convert the contents back into format that will allow me to display it properly.

```
<textarea name="tinycontent" class="form-control" 
id="textFromContentEditor" value=""></textarea>
<div id="textContent" style="display:none"></div>
```

```
var sectionContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
sectionContent = $('#textContent').text(sectionContent).html();

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/CreateNoteContent',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       headerID: headerID,
       categoryID: categoryID,
       sectionContent: sectionContent
    },
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == false) {
            toastr.error("Cannot create new content")
        } else {
            toastr.success("Successfully created new content")
            $("#feed-" + releaseID).trigger('click');
            jumpTo(scrollPos);
        }
     }
});
```

My input into tinyMCE: Hello World

What gets stored in the db: `<p>Hello World</p>`
I want to be able to display just the text contents in the view.

Comment: Try `$('#textContent').html(sectionContent);`

Comment: Aside from the issue: remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice, and you don't need it here anyway

Answer (score 0):

I am certainly not very good at js, ajax and so on, but this is what I did in my project to display html in one of my divs from the pages -tag.

```
var blobs = document.getElementById('your-div-Id').innerHTML = "<h4>somethingRandom</h4>";
```

OBS! I believe this is javascript and therefor might not be the right solution.

Hope this helps!